# Call sproc with temp tables from SSIS in visual studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am new to SSIS and would appreciate any help on my issue below - 
I have a stored procedure which does not take any input and returns a temp table. This is used for data validation and will be run every day thus, I need to create an SSIS package for the same (the requirement is such). I created an Execute SQL task where I have the result set in a variable of type Object but I want to add a condition of checking rowcount >1 and if yes then write to an excel file.

Thanks,
Hiral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer depends on whether you are using SSIS 2012+ or 2008.
Assuming you are with SSIS 2012+:
Approach - declare variable type int for rowcount. Process received Object variable in Foreach loop, more details and screenshots are available in [this article](http://www.select-sql.com/mssql/loop-through-ado-recordset-in-ssis.html). Inside loop - increment variable. Then you can do a conditional execution based on rowcount variable value > 0.
Alternatives - valid for SSIS 2008 as well:

1. Object with result set is nothing more than a .NET dataset. Create a Script task which counts rows in the first table of the dataset, and stores this in a variable. Then use this variable in package as described above.
2. Instead of using Execute SQL Script task for SP run, use DataFlow with OLE DB Source and specify the stored procedure as the data source. Then you can count the resulting rows, store value in a variable etc.

Comment: Yes I am using SSIS 2012 and your answer did help! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Change property  Retainsameconnection  =true   for connection manager

Doing so you can access temp table created in previous step .

Answer (score 0):

You could use a global temp table instead if you want the creation done in a separate step. But this comes with its own issues like being accessible to everyone/every process.